# Variable output PSU switch configuration

Tags: power-supply, switches

So I am designing a switchable voltage 9V/18V power supply and was wondering, what's the best way to switch between outputs, that's the current schematic I came up with:
[image: Current design]
*[Original image size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RVxl.png)*

So my question is, will this work and is this the best way or is there a better one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch the outputs of the regulators. That way you bypass the problem relieved by AaronD and you don't take the risk to have the regulators doing weird things the first ms when they are powered since they are always powered (but I'm not 100% sure about that last part, maybe the regulators are stable even when they have just been powered, but prevention is better than cure...).

You can also switch both input and ouput (using two bridge rectifiers to avoid the transformer tap switching), you've already planned a DPDT relay. You don't get startup instabilities immunity but you get rid of the problem of backpowering the ouputs of the regulators and you don't power the unused regulator.

Comment: It's possible that he's switching the transformer to get better efficiency.  If the startup characteristics are okay, then that might be a good design choice.

Comment: Better efficiency? how?

Comment: Thank you for answer, that would probably save me from an output switch but set me back another bridge, I guess it's not that much of a big deal. Initially I was thinking of saving power by keeping the regulators unpowered when not in use.

Comment: Assuming that they're linear regulators, which the 7800 series are, current out = current in.  And they're dropping whatever difference in voltage there is between in and out.  Less voltage drop = less power dissipated in the regulators = better efficiency.

Comment: A powered regultor but not used should not consume much, maybe hundred of µA at max I guess. Edit: then you can switch both input and ouput, you've already planned a DPDT relay, switch only the positive and voila :)

Comment: Thanks for input, I will see a bit if someone comes with even more clever answer, if not I Will accept this one

Comment: especially since with a single pole switch I'd have less wires between the pcb and front panel, which I much prefer

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a possibility.

Comment: Accepting, I decided to go with a single pole and toggle the output, trivial power losses are not a concern and since I am going to have 4 of these same circuits on the board, the less wires, the better

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I haven't seen someone switch it there before, but it looks like it should almost work.  The only problem that I see is that the 18V setting will try to put that 18V back into the output of the 9V regulator.  I don't think it'll appreciate that.

The 9V setting has potentially the same problem, but I think it's okay because it's less than 18V and the diode from out to in will effectively power the 18V regulator to the point that it doesn't blow up.

Fix the 18V setting, and I think you're good.

Comment: Great answer, how would I protect it, add a third switch pole to output? Diodes on both positive outputs(that'd create some unwanted voltage drop though)?

Comment: DPDT switches and smaller are easy to get.  A bit harder for 3P and above.  I would go with the diodes and boost the regulators' outputs a bit to compensate.

Comment: good point, but since efficiency is not that big of a concern, I might go with just switching the outputs